# found nil while unwrapping in UserDefaults

Tags: swift, xcode, action

I want to save the Date to userDefaults.

Button(action: {

```
                var date = Date()
                if date != nil{
                    date = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "myDate") as! Date
                }
                print(date)
            }) {
            ........(design stuff)
            }
```

Tested also: let date = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "myDate") as! Date

But I always get Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

Comment: Firstly you are force unwrapping your response from UserDefaults, either use an 'if let', a 'guard let' or nil-coalescing. That allow you to handle nil situations. Secondly where are you storing the date in UserDefaults, you should show that code in your question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Check if the object is available in `UserDefaults` before you force cast it using `!`. Always cast optionals safely using `if let` or `guard let`.

To save the date:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(myDate, forKey: "myDate")
```

To retrieve the date:

```
if let object = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "myDate") as? Date {
    date = object
} else {
    print("No object for key myDate in UserDefaults")
}
```

Comment: Ok. I get No object for key myDate in UserDefaults. What can I do? I want to save the date.

Comment: Save the date in UserDefaults before you try to fetch it. `UserDefaults.standard.set(myDate, forKey: "myDate")`

Comment: The question clearly says "I want to _save_ the Date to userDefaults" and this answer is reading from UserDefaults. Why post such an irrelevant answer and why was it even accepted?

Comment: Added the part to save the date in the post too.